# pop-up password input, then submit the popup

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a web-page with a list of usernames (this is for PHP based application)... I want to achieve that by clicking over some username to optain a popup window which will open with a password input field and submit button. After Password would be typed, need to press Submit... The result should be that Popup windows will disappear and main page will login by username and password (from pop-up).

Hope I could describe clear my problem. In case of unclear things, please do not hesitate to ask me. I will appreciate any kind of support! Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Are the "usernames" hyperlinked anywhere at the minute? You could pass through the id.. site.com/users/password.php?user_id=1 and then prompt them to check it from the popup from the ID..

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? (you can't expect people to write the entire thing for you, but we will help you with specific problems or questions)

Comment: the problem I do not know how to create the pop_up with input field and submit button

Comment: Phorce: thank you for the suggestion - I will try this way too. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a more complicated way and a simpler way with some trade-ins.

First the easy solution:

- User puts in password and presses submit
- If the password is correct, the site sets a cookie that contains the userid of the submitted  popup
- On the main page then you would have to refresh and your server would see the cookie and you could send the secure content over

The trade-in is that you'd have to refresh the original page.

Now to more complicated way:

- You have a permanent websocket connection (IE doesn't support this I think) between the server and the main client page.
- When the user submits the form the server sends some new data (the page that would have been loaded in the reload of the prev. example) via the websocket

I would go for the easier version because it has better support and is easier to implement.

Comment: I think both ways are a bit too complicated for such a relatively simple problem ;).

Personally I'd go with the hidden `div` option proposed by ethrbunny.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will explain once more time: I have a small PHP-based application with already defined users. So I have a we-page with pictures of users (like Adam, David, Marin and so on). I was thinking how to do, by clicking the picture to have a POPUP with password to that user and then by submiting to login. One way, might be HREF the ID and other way by using javascrip like ONCLICK or something like this... Hope to find the direction...

Answer (score 3):

You could do this a number of ways. The first (and prob easiest) that comes to mind would be a DIV on the page that starts out hidden. When you click on a username you move the div to the appropriate location, display it and collect the input. The DIV has the 'login' button and redirects to all the relevant FORM bits.

Comment: using jqueryui dialog would make this implementation really easy.

Comment: Please, I will appreciate some guidance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp  use an 'onclick' to get some script to move the div into place (location: absolute) and then display it. You can get the location of the url via  something like http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mouseclickeventcoordinates.htm